# How much does each action contribute to your per-battle player score?

Tags: pokemon-unite

After each battle in Pokémon Unite, the game calculates a per-player score based on their performance in the match.

[image: Pokémon Unite - After Battle Report]

I'm referring to the score in the rightmost column in the table on the right side of the above screenshot.

According to [serebii.net](https://www.serebii.net/pokemonunite/score.shtml), this score is calculated based on the goal points a player scored + their KOs and assists. However, it doesn't say *how* each element affects your score.

Here's what I would like to know:

- What formula is used to calculate the final player score?
- Is the score bounded? What's the highest possible score? I suspect it's 100, which is the highest score I've seen, 100 is a pretty typical ceiling for rating performance.
- What would a player need to do to achieve a score of '100'?

Comment: Some observations: the minimum is 10, and the maximum I've reached is 99. I suspect there are hidden factors though. I will try to do some research soon. :)

Comment: my gut feeling says that rather than being a real 'score' this is like a ranking or percentile of all performances by players with that pokemon. So a score of '50' would mean, half of all games with venausaur have better performances, and half of them have worse. If that would be the case, it's not really possible to know what kind of formula is used or what timeframe are included in these rankings. Reasons that make me believe this is the case are on one hand the typical spread you see after a match (30-60 for losers, 70-95 for winners) and that good performing suports often have higher score

Comment: I've been able to confirm that the player score is based off ofmore than just goal points, kills, and assists. I have records 2 matches where a player got 27 goal points, 0 kills, and 0 assists. In one, the player's score was 36. In the other, the player's score was 39.

Comment: I can now confirm that it's possible to get 100, still not sure about all the factors though.

Comment: @BenoitEsnard Can you share a screenshot of the battle report? I'm compiling a spreadsheet of battle scores to see if I can back into a formula. I have a few theories I'm working through: 1) each input has diminishing returns and a cap after which it no longer contributes to player score, and 2) your score is affected by the performance of other players in the match (i.e. everyone is scored on a curve vs the highest scoring player).

Comment: @Shaun: here you are: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/154mkjIMNCHYtIw9ZmJfjWo-f9qcB-ORe :)